# add cc and bcc in the address while sending the mail using java

Tags: java, email

I am sending the email using the java . I want to send the mail as bcc and cc options also in the address how is it possible. I am using the following code.

```
   public String sendemail(String xtomail,String xsub,String xbody)
    {
   final String username ="adeshsingh86@gmail.com";
    final String password ="passwordhere";


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        //message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("adeshsingh86@gmail.com"));
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            //InternetAddress.parse("kmukesh2008@gmail.com"));
                            InternetAddress.parse(xtomail));
        //message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                    message.setSubject(xsub);
 // message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
//          + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

                        message.setText(xbody);

        Transport.send(message);

        return "Y";

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                return "N";
        //throw new RuntimeException(e);

            }


}
```

Comment: Since you are already using `Message.RecipientType.TO` in your code doing CC and BCC should be intuitive

Comment: message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, recipients); // where recipients is an instance of Address[]. Similarly, for BCC.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You set your recipients with the setter method. Look at how you add it, you'll see you add a Message.RecipientType.TO. Same can be done with CC and BCC. You could use the addRecipient method for this too.

ex:

```
message.addRecipient(RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(
            "your@email.com"));
message.addRecipient(RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(
            "yourOther@email.com"));
```

more info: [MimeMessage API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html)

Comment: Note that you need to send by using Transport.send(MimeMessage) and NOT Transport.send(MimeMessage, Address[]), because the latter will override the bcc recipients you add.