# How to set CC and sender name for android Gmail API?

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api

From Google official website, this is a method to create a email before sending.

```
public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to,
                                              String from,
                                              String subject,
                                              String bodyText)
                throws MessagingException {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);

            email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setText(bodyText);
            return email;
        }
```

I can't find the API which I can set for CC email address and sender name. 
I searched on internet and also can't find the answer. Please have a help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set recipients with the setter method

```
  message.addRecipient(RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.addRecipient(RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(to));
```

Comment: great, let me check . How about set sender name ? @MCZ

Answer (score 1):

you can try following way

```
 message.addRecipient(RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(
        "your@email.com"));
 message.addRecipient(RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(
        "yourOther@email.com"));
```

credit to [him](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15428191/6478047)